# How to deploy a python code on firebase server

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a python code which I want to deploy on firebase as my Application  database is firebase realtimeDB.

A part of this APP is developed on python so I want to integrate in with my App. Which can be done by deploying python piece of code on firebase.

I am unable to find a way to deploy a python code via firebase hosting.

Anyone have any solution I would really appreciate it.

I have tried to deploy it with firebase CLI tools. But I think it supports Javascript

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040767/can-python-flask-websites-be-hosted-on-firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy any backend code with Firebase Hosting.  It only serves static content.  You will have to look into other ways of running your backend, such as Cloud Functions or App Engine.

Comment: Seems it is not right anymore. This publication shows python server can be deployed on Firebase https://medium.com/firebase-developers/hosting-flask-servers-on-firebase-from-scratch-c97cfb204579

Comment: @Gleichmut Firebase Hosting still only supports static content.  You can connect it to different products to run backend code, such as the ones I listed in the answer.  But those products are not the same as Firebase Hosting.